# Companion Books for Rudin's PMA

Tags: analysis, self-learning, book-recommendation

S.E friends,

I am a college sophomore with double majors in mathematics and microbiology. I wrote this email to seek your recommendation on selecting the introductory analysis textbook, particularly one that complement with Rudin's PMA well. Starting on this Fall, I will be taking Analysis I course, which uses Rudin's PMA. I will be finishing Calculus II (text: Calculus with Analytic Geometry, George Simmon; computational), and I also have been studying linear algebra (Serge Lang's Introduction to LA) and mathematical proof (Chartrand) book independently and will complete both subjects by mid-May. I was thinking studying Apostol/Spivak during Summer to prepare for Analysis I but I thought it would be best to just enter the analysis with Rudin's PMA and other analysis textbooks since it will be impossible to finish Apostol/Spivak during Summer and that time can be better spent on Rudin's PMA and others. I have enough money to purchase two other analysis textbooks that can complement Rudin's PMA well and help me to learn the analysis. My mind is on Apostol (Mathematical Analysis), Pugh, Ross, Strichartz, Lang, and Abbott, but I am not sure of their contents....unfortunately, those books have been either checked out or in hold at my university's math library. Please give me recommendation of two analysis textbooks that can supplement Rudin's PMA well!

Sincerely,

PK

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly recommend a classic one : The Elements of Real Analysis, Second Edition: by Robert G. Bartle

Answer (score 1):

Get a more intuitive book. Rudin is very overrated and provides little intuition. Plus, after chapter 8, the whole thing turns into one big dumpster fire. Forego hardcore delta-epsilon proofs and try to develop intuition. Apostol is better with that. Get used to being somewhat sloppy and get a handle on sending expressions to zero, making perturbation arguments, and building a solid toolkit for dealing with proofs.

After you've built up intuition, then try to tackle some of Rudin's exercises.

Comment: Thanks!  The should I get both Apostol's Mathematical Analysis and Rudin's PMA?  How about Pugh, Ross, and Abbott?

Comment: Pick a book with pictures. If it doesn't have pictures, it's no good for you. Further Mathematics for Mathematical Analysis by Sydsaeter and Hammond, Applied Analysis by Nachtergale, or even learning complex variables in between would build good intuition. A good resource is Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering and Science by Schneider. All are fairly intuitive and bridge the gam between calculus and advanced mathematics nicely.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion.  I actually picked up Apostol's Mathematical Analysis today from a library and I actually find it quite readable and understandable.  In this case, should I keep reading that book along with Rudin's PMA or would you still recommend me to start with basics?

Comment: Apostol is good. Any reading can't hurt; however, I would recommend you supplement with basics/ draw lots of pictures.